# How to set the UITableViewCell height based on component within it

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have created a subclass of `UITableViewCell` which contains a `UITextView`. When the text in the `UITextView` is set, it automatically resizes so that the height increases but the width stays the same.

I now want to use the method shown below to dynamically set the height of each `UITableViewCell` based on the height of the `UITextView` within it.

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Some code to pull in the subclassed UITableViewCell & set 
    // the height based on the UITextView within it.
}
```

Please can someone advise on how/if this is possible? To be clear it is getting my custom cell from this method that is causing me the issue, obviously I can just cast it but that doesn't seem right to me. Please can someone advise on how to do this?

Comment: Depends on your requirement. Please specify more then i can answer.

Comment: Imho it all will not help. You need to control number of lines property in your text view in order to keep it inside of your cell in all situations (for example, in edit mode).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a UITextView with the correct width, and then set the text on the textview.
Call `[textview sizeToFit]`. Get the height from the textview, then add whatever additional height you need to be equivalent to what it would be if it were within your UITableViewCell subclass.

Using NSString's `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:` would be nice, but in my experience this will often break the string in different places than a UITextView of the same size, so it is not reliable. Your text will often require more or fewer lines in the UITextView than NSString's `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:` suggests it should.

Answer (score 1):

Each time `UITextView` content changes it needs to recalculate and update related cell heigh. You can not just set new cell heigh, `tableView` should ask it by calling its delegate method `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` instead. To force `tableView` to recalculate its cell sizes call empty `[tableView beginUpdates]` / `[tableView endUpdates]` block.
 There is a ReminderSample demo in my [TableKit](https://github.com/onegray/UITableKit) library, that shows this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Use NSString's [sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/NSString_UIKit_Additions/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/sizeWithFont%3aconstrainedToSize%3alineBreakMode%3a) on the string that goes in the UITextView.  I add ~15px to the height returned to give it some breathing room.

Answer (score 0):

This is a real world example. In this app only the single cell in the third section is resized, if you want any cell to be resized, you should save the size (in my example descriptionLableSize) in a NSMutableDictionary and use it in `tableView:cellForIndexPath:`

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *description = [self.modelObject valueForKey:@"descriptionText"];
    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(280.0f, MAXFLOAT);

    //if needed save the size in a dictionary for each indexPath
    descriptionLableSize = [description sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17] constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    if (indexPath.section == 2){
        NSUInteger h = descriptionLableSize.height + 20;
        h = (h < 44) ? 44:h;
        return h;
    }
    return 44.0;
}



-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    //....
    if (section == 2) {

        NSString *description = [self.modelObject valueForKey:@"descriptionText"];
        cell.textLabel.text = description;
        [cell.textLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
        cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17.0];
        cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;

    }

    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

    return cell;

}
```